# TableView dynamic height when adding content

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a TableView in which I add some items with a button.

I want make is height dynamic and don't display empty row. So the height have to be resized when I add an item.

For example :

With 3 items

[image]

with more item

[image]

But not like that

[image]

How can I know the height to add to the total height each time I add an item ?

Comment: You can find the the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945817/javafx-adapt-tableview-height-to-number-of-rows