# How to make TableView's height match actual row count in data model

Tags: layout, javafx, javafx-8

I use TableView for a small table of few entries that should consume only as much screen space as needed to display them.

TableView by default creates lots of blank rows that have no backend model data and consumes space. I've performed a search there and discovered only a way to color all blank rows with solid white and let them still steal screen space from other widgets.

So, is it possible at all to get rid of empty rows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX - Adapt TableView height to number of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945817/javafx-adapt-tableview-height-to-number-of-rows)

Comment: @eckig You are right, this answer is a duplicate. But solution proposed in the existed question is a hack not applicable to general cases.

Comment: Why is it a hack? The solution used public API only, no special Skin or CSS magic done..

Comment: It sets row height to predefined constant. It supposes that size for caption is related to row size as 1:1.01. It does not prevent TableView from creating orphan TableCells, it just recalculate table height and force TableView delete rows after resizing, but rows are still created.

Comment: some more ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26298337/203657

Comment: @eckig - I agree with OP here, magic numbers are evil, always ;-)

Comment: @ayvango It is not a predefined constant. The fixed cell size is just a number, you can set it to 10, 300, 50000 whatever you like. It just there to show you how it is done and it can only work if you can assert that all rows have the same height. The rest of my example is done via Bindings..

Comment: @eckig your created a TableCell implementation, managed somehow to calculate its height. And after that you have applied new css to the table and see how it gets disturbed by a code constant that does not match to css. As for the second link, I find it more promising

Comment: @ayvango are we talking about the same thing here? My answer does not use a custom cell nor does it use custom CSS. Plain Java code, no internal API and no constant values. Just a single number that can freely be adjusted. Im out..

Comment: @eckig others may found complicated table views with custom cells and css usefull. And they still face the same problem with blank lines. So you need a solution that can address this cases too.